# What can be the reason for AWS ECS stop deploying with new task revision?

Tags: docker, github-actions, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

Our system runs:

`github actions -> aws ecr aws ecr -> aws ecs (test, production cluster)  aws ecs -> aws ec2 (test, production server)`

But now it has stopped deploying, so we get up 1 desired task, 1 pending task, but it wont deploy it and only generates failed task over and over again. The new task definition revision is exact same as the new, with different container used. So, now I am kinda stuck here..

```
    - name: Deploy Amazon ECS task definition
      uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecs-deploy-task-definition@v1
      with:
        task-definition: ${{ steps.task-def.outputs.task-definition }}
        service: ${{ env.ECS_SERVICE }}
        cluster: ${{ env.ECS_CLUSTER }}
        wait-for-service-stability: true
```

Have tried to go through the github actions and Dockerfiles, but these have been working before. Cannot see anything wrong with them. I have also tried to update service to the old task revision and then it deploys. So, logically it has to be the container that is failing somehow.

I don't get any errors in github workflow, it finish all tasks easily.
I don't get any specific error in the deployment either, just that task failed.
What more can it be?

Comment: Regarding "**it has to be the container that is failing**", did you try to verify it?

Comment: no, I didn't verify it but since it doesn't deploy and it suddenly stop deploying I was assuming this.

Comment: Your container is failing to run. You need to be looking at the container's logs to see what the error is.

Comment: it kinda doesn't give any errors on the logs, because the new container is not even deployed.

Comment: [19/Mar/2023:12:53:57 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2154 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"

Comment: It shows the logs for test-container-backend:57

what is failing is test-container-backend:67

Comment: You're deploying to EC2, so there should be ECS service logs on the target EC2 server. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/logs.html

Answer (score 0):

After some work on the system I thought I would give people short information what the case was. As a beginner I added "php artisan queue:work" in a script, which made it run forever. Adding an entrypoint file and supervisord with the needed commands was the right approach for this task, so now it works as a charm.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).